# How to summarize key statistics by two variables?

Tags: r

Here is some sample code:

```
dat = data.frame(income = c(100,200,300,400,500,600), 
                 sex = c("M","M","M", "F","F","F"), 
                 num.kid = c(1,2,3,1,2,3))
```

I want to produce a 2-dimensional table that summarizes the key statistics (e.g. mean and var) of income distribution by sex and num.kid.

For example, `table(dat$sex, dat$num.kid)` would give me a 2x3 table with `sex` as rows and `num.kid` as columns, but the table would be filled with the count of those combinations. How can I bring a third variable (e.g. income) into the table? How can I fill the table with mean or var of `income` by `sex` and `num.kid`? This is almost like filling out an Excel pivot table using R code.

Comment: Hi Ruser, could you please include a `data.frame` of the expected results?

Comment: Sounds like you really need something like `dplyr::group_by`/`dplyr::summarize`, base R's `by` or `ave`, or something similar from `data.table`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a sample using your data:

```
library(dplyr)
dat %>% 
  group_by(sex) %>%  
  summarise(mean = mean(income), 
            var = var(income),
            sd = sd(income))
```

You can put multiple fields in the `group_by` statement.

Comment: Ugh, I know you can use the dplyr package, but I'm was wondering if there is a more basic command to do this.